# Shell script for BackupPC notification not working

Tags: linux, shell-script, backup

I would like an email notification everytime a successful backup has taken place using BackupPC which I have installed on Ubuntu 16.04 server. BackupPC doesn't email you notifications unless a backup has failed. When I run the following script, I get the email saying its "failed".

I place the following in the backup settings:

```
$Conf{DumpPostUserCmd} = 

/var/lib/backuppc/backuppc_notification_email.sh $xferOK $host $type 
$client $hostIP $share $XferMethod $sshPath $cmdType
```

And here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to send simple email
# Email To ?
EMAIL="myemail@mydomain.com"
# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="/var/lib/backuppc/emailmessage.txt"
# Grab the status variables
xferOK=$1
host=$2
type=$3
client=$4
hostIP=$5
share=$6
XferMethod=$7
sshPath=$8
cmdType=$9

# Check if backup succeeded or not.
if [[ $xferOK == 1 ]]; then
        STATUS="has been SUCCESSFUL"
else
        STATUS="has FAILED"
fi

# email subject
SUBJECT="[BackupPC] $STATUS for host: $client"

# Email text/message
echo "The filesystem backup for $host $STATUS" > $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "-----------------------------------------" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Type: $type" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Client: $client" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Host: $host" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Host IP: $hostIP" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "Share: $share" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "XferMethod: $XferMethod" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "sshPath: $sshPath" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
echo "cmdType: $cmdType" >>$EMAILMESSAGE

# send an email using /bin/mail
/usr/sbin/sendmail -v "$EMAIL" "$SUBJECT" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

The following is the email message I receive:

```
The filesystem backup for  has FAILED
-----------------------------------------
Type: 
Client: 
Host: 
Host IP: 
Share: 
XferMethod: 
sshPath: 
cmdType:
```

I would like to know why the email doesn't have the relevant information as stated in my shell script, and why it says FAILED?

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting command and add semicolon in the end:

```
 $Conf{DumpPostUserCmd} = '/var/lib/backuppc/backuppc_notification_email.sh $xferOK $host $type $client $hostIP $share $XferMethod $sshPath $cmdType';
```

From [BackupPC Documentation](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#Configuration-File):

> The configuration file is a perl script that is executed by BackupPC,
>   so you should be careful to preserve the file syntax (punctuation,
>   quotes etc) when you edit it. It is recommended that you use CVS, RCS
>   or some other method of source control for changing config.pl.

Also, you can use [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for creating email message:

```
cat << _EOF_ > "$EMAILMESSAGE"
The filesystem backup for $host $STATUS 
-----------------------------------------
Type: $type
Client: $client
Host: $host
Host IP: $hostIP
Share: $share
XferMethod: $XferMethod
sshPath: $sshPath
cmdType: $cmdType
_EOF_
```